# Unable to get the room list from online exchange using EWS Managed API?

Tags: c#, outlook, office365

My client has created rooms on online exchange. I can see list of rooms at outlook.office365.com

I am following this url ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn643730(v=exchg.150).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn643730%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)) to get the room list from exchange online, but empty list is being returned.

What am i doing wrong? Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the GetRooms and GetRoomLists methods, which at a glance appear to be exactly what you are looking for, actually require that one or more "Room Lists" be created on the Exchange server, with one or more existing rooms added to the relevant "Room Lists".  Only once this is done will the methods you refer to actually produce any results.

Unfortunately all my research into this topic has (so far) found that the ONLY way anyone can create a room list is via a PowerShell command on the exchange server.  It can't be configured through Office 365 settings or through any hosted exchange provider's interface (such as hosted exchange made available via Parallels systems).

If you do have powershell access, try something like this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633471%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

They way I did was to name all conference rooms with the prefix Conf. For example, ConfAAA1, ConfBBB2, ConfCCC3, etc. Then to retrieve a list of all rooms:

```
    List<NameResolution> result = ExchangeService.ResolveName("Conf",
 ResolveNameSearchLocation.ContactsThenDirectory, true).ToList<NameResolution>();
```